# How can I get active page in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to get the active page in the eclipse editor. When I googled it up, I found the code below​:

```java
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) page.getActiveEditor();
```

However, when I use this code, it generates the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kr.ac.jbnu.ssel.instantfeedback.views.InstantFeedbackView$1.elementChanged(InstantFeedbackView.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor$3.run(DeltaProcessor.java:1662)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.notifyListeners(DeltaProcessor.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fireReconcileDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:1504)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fire(DeltaProcessor.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:207)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**Add**
This is my elementChanged() function. It is in the method.

```java
private void addListenerToCheckChange_save() {
  JavaCore.addElementChangedListener(new IElementChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent event) {
      IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
      IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
      IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
      ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) page.getActiveEditor();
      IJavaElement javaElement = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editor.getEditorInput());
      if (javaElement instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
        ITextSelection sel = (ITextSelection) editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        IJavaElement selected = null;
        try {
          ...
        } catch (JavaModelException JME) {
          JME.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And i tried to modify it to implement IElementChangedListener in my view class. This is modified one.

```java
@Override
public void elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent arg0) {
  Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
      IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
      IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
      ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) page.getActiveEditor();
      IJavaElement javaElement = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editor.getEditorInput());
      if (javaElement instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
        ITextSelection sel = (ITextSelection) editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        IJavaElement selected = null;
        try {
          ...
        } catch (JavaModelException JME) {
          JME.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  });       
}
```

However, modified one was not working...

Comment: The code snippet is the right one to obtain the currently active editor. The posted stacktrace does not relate to the snippet. Set a breakpoint on `wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();` and debug-step through the code.

Comment: This error occurs when i do win.getActivePage().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting null for the active workbench window from:

```
IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
```

This is because your code is being run in a thread which is not the main UI thread - `getActiveWorkbenchWindow` returns null in this case.

To use UI operations like this you will need to arrange to run your code in the UI thread, perhaps by using `Display.asyncExec`. Something like:

```java
public void elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent event) {

   ... code not run in UI thread

   Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() ->
     {
       ... code to run in UI thread
     });
}
```

(using Java 8 lambda, for older Java's use a `Runnable`).

Comment: This code is used in end of createPartControl(). When should i use it?

Comment: The stack trace you show is for code running in an anonymous class with an `elementChanged` method (probably an `IElementChangedListener` listener). The code there is running in a different thread. You must change that code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that.

Comment: Hmm.... i tried to run it in createPartControl(Composite parent) as parent.getDisplay.asyncExec(). However, sometime after, same error occurs. Is it wrong?

Comment: You must run the `asyncExec` inside the `elementChanged` method - see example.

Comment: Can't find what? Somewhere in your `InstantFeedbackView` class there is an anonymous class with a `elementChanged` method.

Comment: Please see my ask... I added additional contents.

Comment: You must use `Display.getDefault()` **not** `Display.getCurrent()`

Comment: Oh, i solve it! I use Display.getCurrent() in my original code. Thank you very very much... I'm sorry to send your time in here too much.